# SQL - How to discard groups of results based on date range (microsoft access)

Tags: sql, date, ms-access, recursion, duplicates

I have an Access database of pathology results for many patients, which often includes many samples collected over a period of time for the same patient. I want to keep the first record for every patient, but discard all subsequent records for the same patient that occurs within 14 days. But if there are more samples after 14 days, keep the first subsequent one, then again discard samples from the following 14 days.

The table has many columns, but the most important are the `patient ID` and the `sample collection date`.

I need to understand how to write an SQL statement to select those initial records, but discard those within the subsequent 14 days. I think it could be related to the `between` command, but I am unsure of how to make the start and end dates variable and how to make it recurse over the whole data set.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do it in one query. You will need to iterate through each patient ID, find their first date, delete anything within 14 days of that, find the next date and repeat. When you say discard, do you mean remove from the table or do you mean remove from the results only? If the latter, then rather than delete you will need to add the patientID's and dates to a temptable to link back in for the final output

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this purely in SQL, but here's some (annotated) VBA code that I think does what you're asking:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim strSql As String
Dim rsPat As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

' Get ourselves an ordered list of unique patients to work through

strSql = "SELECT PatientID " _
       & " FROM tblPatientSamplesExample" _
       & " GROUP BY PatientID" _
       & " ORDER BY PatientID"

Set rsPat = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)

With rsPat

    If _
        Not (.BOF And .EOF) _
    Then

        .MoveFirst

        Do While Not .EOF

            ' For the patient we're working on, make another list that shows the records
            ' in our table for this particular patient, ordered by the sample collection date

            Dim rsPatSampRecs As DAO.Recordset
            Dim refDate As Variant
            Dim currDate As Variant

            strSql = "SELECT * " _
                   & " FROM tblPatientSamplesExample" _
                   & " WHERE PatientID=" & rsPat!PatientID _
                   & " ORDER BY SampleCollectionDate ASC"

            Set rsPatSampRecs = db.OpenRecordset(strSql)

            With rsPatSampRecs

                If _
                    Not (.BOF And .EOF) _
                Then

                    .MoveFirst
                    ' Set the earliest sample collection date for this patient as the reference date to use
                    refDate = CDbl(rsPatSampRecs!SampleCollectionDate)

                    Do While Not .EOF

                        ' Set the current record's sample collection date for this patient as the current date to compare
                        currDate = CDbl(rsPatSampRecs!SampleCollectionDate)

                        ' if currDate is 14 or more greater than refDate then update the refDate to the currDate
                        If _
                            currDate >= (refDate + 14) _
                        Then

                            refDate = currDate

                        End If

                        ' if currDate is not the same as the refDate delete the record from
                        ' tblPatientSamplesExample by matching PatientSampleID of this temp recordset
                        ' to the one in the actual table

                        If _
                            currDate <> refDate _
                        Then

                            strSql = "DELETE * FROM tblPatientSamplesExample" _
                                   & " WHERE PatientSampleID=" & rsPatSampRecs!PatientSampleID

                            CurrentDb.Execute strSql

                        End If

                        .MoveNext

                    Loop

                End If

            End With

            rsPatSampRecs.Close
            Set rsPatSampRecs = Nothing
            .MoveNext

        Loop

    End If

End With


rsPat.Close

Set rsPat = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-J5B7nFljZiVzYyNGtwbk9YLUk/view?usp=sharing) my mock-up Access file too. I've interpreted "discard records" to mean "delete records", so be careful before implementing this (take a back-up of your data).

Comment: Just realised I missed the line `CurrentDb.Execute strSql`, which will be quite important when it comes to deleting the records you don't want! Answer has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Max() function?  You can use it to select the latest SampleDate for each Patient ID

Something like this:

```
Select PatentID, Max(SampleDate)
From SpecimenTable
Where CollectionDate between Date1 and Date2
Group By PatientID
```

You will need to include each field in the select statement other than the Max(SampleDate) in the group by statement.

Answer (score 0):

Purely "aircode", I don't have a ton of time to devote to this but if it doesn't make sense then maybe someone else can use it to come up with a complete solution:

```
'Keep the first record in the first 14 days
Select PatentID, Max(SampleDate)
From SpecimenTable
Where CollectionDate between Now() and DateAdd("d", Now(), -14)
Group By PatientID

UNION ALL

'Keep the first record of everything after the first 14 days
Select PatentID, Max(SampleDate)
From SpecimenTable
Where CollectionDate < DateAdd("d", Now(), -15)
Group By PatientID
```

Obviously you can't use comments in a query, so you need to remove these.  I just put them in to show my thought process.